# What are the differences between Germany's major political parties?

Tags: parties, germany, ideology

For example, I don't know what the major differences are between the [Greens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliance_90/The_Greens) and the [SPD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Democratic_Party_of_Germany). On a crude left to right line, where would you place the major parties? Comparing them to US parties, where would you place them?

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE! What research did you undertake before asking this?

Comment: There are so many possible criteria to differentiate parties. Are you interested in some of them particularly? Voter demographics, regional strongholds, personalities, political manifestos, historical tracks. Stances on abortion, religion. taxes, saving the Earth, unemployment benefits health care, speed limits, animal welfare, carrying weapons, foreign policies, the army, surveillance, gay marriages, education, immigration, ... just to name a few. And no parties are completely equal in any of these things.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Compared to US parties, **all** of them with the possible exception of the AfD are leftist. Most favor public healthcare for all, for instance, and a government role in the pension system.

The German system of proportional representation with a cutoff encourages large and medium parties, not very small ones. A party which consistently scores below 5% is likely going to dissipate. A new party breaking above the 5% level happens perhaps once in a generation.

From left to right, and trying to force the federal and sixteen state organizations of each into a single paragraph:

- **Die Linke**
  Literally "the left," they are in favor of legislation aiding poor workers. They also have some political baggage from being the successor of the Communist party in East Germany. For instance, they are anti-NATO and to some degree pro-Russia.
- **Die Grünen**
  Formed out of environmentalist and peace movements in the West, and the democracy movement in the East. They have grown from a special-interest, "niche" party into being the senior partner in state-level governing coalitions. Still quite environmentalist. Their leftist bend somewhat conflicts with the attitudes of wealthy environmentalists who can *afford* to buy organic meat, etc. and expect others to do the same.
- **SPD**
  Social democrats. Originally labour, now with many supporters in the civil service and similar jobs. Once they were one of the big, non-special-interest parties, they are much diminished in recent years. In parts this is due to being the junior partner of the Union for the last decade. They're being ground up between die Linke and the Union.
- **FDP**
  Liberal democrats. Another "niche" party supporting tax breaks and freedom of business for small businessmen, etc.
- **CDU** and **CSU** (together the **Union**)
  The CSU in Bavaria and the CDU in the rest of Germany call themselves Christian Democrats. They are more conservative and more likely to be religious than the other *democrat* parties, but they are the other of the big non-special-issue parties, covering a broad platform. Some of their workers' advocates have been nicknamed "Sacred Heart Marxists" for their faith-inspired support of government welfare. Others are "nationalist conservatives."
- **AfD**
  The Alternative for Germany developed from an anti-Euro (and especially anti-bailout) platform over anti-immigrant policies to an authoritarian worldview. Many have pro-Russia and conspiracy-theorist worldviews, and a vocal faction are fascists.

Historically, there has almost always been a **coalition government**. This would be either the SPD or the Union as the senior partner, with one or perhaps two smaller ones to get the necessary majority. This has broken down in recent years when the Union and SPD formed a "grand" coaltion which has become increasingly less grand over time.

On the federal level, the Greens, SPD, FDP and Union have been involved in governments. At the state level, die Linke were included as well. All other significant parties are unwilling to work with the AfD, but eastern CDU state-level parties are wavering in this regard.

Comment: I was drafting an answer which was basically saying the same things. +1. But there is certainly a lot of nuance which could be nitpicked on a topic which is as broad and opinion-based as this. It might be worth to remind the reader of this answer that this is really just a 1km birds-eye view of the political landscape of Germany. For example, a lot of the länder-branches of these parties have positions and priorities which differ from those of the federal parties.

Comment: @Philipp, do you see any point where an one-sentence addition would clarify the *federal* position?

Comment: Just one sentence? One could write a whole book about this (and people have). I would just find it useful to remind people that this answer does not and can not cover all the nuances of the political landscape of Germany.

Comment: Re: "Compared to US parties", this isn't a united-states question, and the O.P hasn't expressed any nation of origin. I feel like the answer stands fine on its own (nice work ^.^), and that para might confuse things a bit.

Comment: @DariM: The OP explicitly asked: _**Comparing them to US parties**, where would you place them?_

Comment: In any comparison with the US, it's worth noting that in EU "conservative" has quite different connotations than in USA; for example, while in both places conservative parties advocate for "moral conservativism" in social policy, if we're talking about economics and governance, I've seen that in USA politics conservative implies a small-government preference, while in EU conservative is more associated with paternalistic big-government preference.

Comment: I’m surprised you put the Greens left of the SPD which doesn’t fit my view of the matter.

Comment: @Jan, that position can be supported but it is not yet mainstream. I was trying to give an overview. Note the last sentence on Greens, which contains a qualifier.

Comment: @Jan The Greens are certainly socially leftist, while being far more authoritarian with regards to the economy than the SPD is.

Comment: I think it's odd that you put emphasis on the fascists in the AfD, but don't mention communists and violent ecological activists in the ranks of the Green and Linke parties.

Comment: @towe Probably because one are a significant, strong fraction while the other two you mention are neglegible overall. (That said, I also have to strongly disagree with your assertion the Greens be authoritarian in regard to the economy in any significant way.)

Comment: @Jan I wish both factions were negligible, but alas neither are. I feel like many of the "greater goals" are very authoritarian - forbidding private transport through excessive taxation, enforcing wind and solar energy irrespective of the required deforestation, *enforcing* political correctness...

Comment: @Jan Perhaps not official goals, but that's exactly what has happened in each state government they're involved in. Just look at the horrible decline of Berlin.

Comment: @towe Funny, as far as I am aware Berlin is not attempting to outlaw cars or cut down forests. (Yes, I am purposefully ignoring the bit where you use a weasel and trigger word; state what that is actually supposed to mean, first.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102062/discussion-between-towe-and-jan).

Comment: @Jan, there **is** a clear tension between the big picture (fewer fossil fuels) and the local one (wind power NIMBY).There can be no question that man-made climate change is real and will have expensive consequences, and that just mitigating this will be painful. Nobody would allow people to pour toxic waste down the drain, so why allow motorists to emit CO2? The obvious answer, it is a reasonable burden to dispose waste properly, but it is not reasonable to stop motorists from driving altogether -- if they take steps to minimize the impact. Remember the outcry when seatbelts were made law?

Comment: @o.m. Not sure what you’re trying to argue but note a chat room exists now.